# winform scroll bar custom

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

Sorry about the translator.
I want to customize the scroll bar with winform.

What I want is the ability to drag the control out of the bar and return to the original value without changing the value when the mouse is raised.

I've tried `scrollbar.mouseLeave`, but it's not immediate and the value has to be outside the client's range so it doesn't change.
It must be completed with winform.
I appreciate your help.

If you scroll out of range of that scrollbar and mouse-up, you want to return to the original value.
The existing value is the value before scrolling.

[image]

Comment: Not quite clear your needs. What is "drag the control out of the bar"? What is "original value"? Please provide more details.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've revised the content a little more.

Comment: Do you mean that: Say scrolling vertically (Top Down) - You move the scroll thumb all the way down. And then It should allow you to move thumb a bit further down and that should 'trigger ' and make scrollbar return to Top most (unscrolled) position.  In algo terms circular queue'ish.

Comment: Must behave like a mouseleave function in winform. If you leave that scroll bar, you have to go back to the value before the scroll works.
I tried using mouseleave, but it didn't work as soon as I left the scrollbar, but as soon as I left the client.

Comment: ex ) private void testScrollBar_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                testScrollBar.Value = preValue;
        }

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior when you drag the thumb and the mouse leaves the client area of the scrollbar is resetting the `Value` property to it's before-dragging-the-thumb-value. You don't need to write any additional code if this is what you want.

However, you can handle the `Scroll` event to override the default behavior to keep the last thumb position or the `Minimum`/`Maximum` values when the mouse pointer leaves the client area of the control:

```cs
private void testScrollBar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    if (!testScrollBar.ClientRectangle.Contains(testScrollBar.PointToClient(MousePosition))
        && e.NewValue != e.OldValue)
    {
        e.NewValue = e.OldValue;
        testScrollBar.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to reset the value to the before-dragging-the-thumb-value only when you release the mouse button:

```cs
private void testScrollBar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.ThumbTrack &&
        !testScrollBar.ClientRectangle.Contains(testScrollBar.PointToClient(MousePosition)))
    {
        e.NewValue = e.OldValue;
        testScrollBar.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

The demo illustrates the three behaviors.

[image: SOQ65712488]

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind response.
The hard part was really simple.
Thanks once again.